# How to decode airflow table dag_run column conf value

Tags: airflow

How do i decode the value of airflow table dag_run column conf value so I can read the value of conf column from the table

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to query the metastore database explicitly for your use case?  Can you explain a little more about the need to directly query the database?  Perhaps include your DAG code for more context?

Airflow exposes the `DagRun` object as part of a [built-in macro](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/macros-ref.html#default-variables) and is accessible through Jinja templates.

Comment: We have scheduled dags that triggers another dag with conf parameters in JSON format. 

We need to design a process to read ariflow metastore table : dag_run table conf column data and I see the value is encoded in the table. I am trying to find ways of how we can decode the conf value and see what parameters what passed to each dag execution. 

Do you know if it can be done at sql level or in python? I am OK with any option

Comment: @Imran, what solution did you find for this ?

Answer (score 3):

I recently ran into the same thing, and it turns out the `conf` column is a binary Pickle string.

I found the answer in the Airflow internal module documentation
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_modules/airflow/models/dagrun.html#DagRun.conf

```py
import pickle

# function to return SQLAlchemy Engine connected to Airflow
engine = get_airflow_db_engine()

# query and convert conf
query = """
    select dag_id, execution_date, state, run_id, conf
    from dag_run
    limit 25
"""
df = pd.read_sql(query, engine)
df['conf'] = df['conf'].apply(lambda x: pickle.loads(x))
```

Comment: Nice find, my team has been struggling with this for days!

Answer (score 0):

I shared my code. I had similar experiences for getting dagrun duration with specific condition. I executed this on scheduler Pod terminal with python shell.

```
import pickle
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from airflow import settings

# get airflow db connection string
sql_alchemy_conn = settings.SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN
engine = create_engine(sql_alchemy_conn)

query="""
SELECT
    end_date - start_date as execution_duration,
    conf
FROM dag_run
where dag_id='xx'
"""
df = pd.read_sql(query, engine)
df['conf'] = df['conf'].apply(lambda x: pickle.loads(x))

# just example for filtering
target_df = df[df['conf'].apply(lambda x: x.get('period') == 'entire')]
```